# script to batch join audio and video together with avconv or something similar

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm new to bash scripting. I need to find a way of joining .wav's and .mp4's (they are of same length) together as there's about a thousand files I need to go through.

Any suggestions and possible examples I could try? There's probably too many ways of doing this, I looked at avconv as it seemed simple to use, but open to other suggestions (vlc, ffmpeg?)

Also saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg) ffmpeg script for a single file:

https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg

The original video and audio file names would be identical except for extension.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be equivalent.

```
for filename in *.mp4; do
    stub="${filename%.*}"
    ffmpeg -i "${stub}.wav" -i "${stub}.mp4" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "newfiles/${stub}.avi"
done
```

Comment: The script is in the same folder as all files, but I'm getting "*.wav: No such file or directory" after running it. I tried adding a full directory path to the first line without any success:

for filename in "/some/path/*.mp4"; do

Comment: I figured out that taking the inverted commas from *.mp4 on the first line fixes this issue.
I now get an encoding error: 'Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input'
here's the full output:
http://pastebin.com/nZA7kFD0
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm stuck making progress, with `for filename in *.mov; 
do
    stub="${filename%.*}" 
    /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8/bin/ffmpeg -i movs/"${stub}".mov -i m4a/"${stub}".m4a -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0:0 -map 1 MERGED_VIDEOS_MOV/"${stub}.mp4"
done`
I just get **movs/.mov: no such file or directory**. I'm pretty certain it's to do with the way ffmpeg is handling escaping, but I've tried pretty much everything!

Comment: That suggests `"${stub}"` is being replaced with nothing. Remove the ffmpeg line and just try echoing out all the values of `$stub` and see if you can see the problem there.

Comment: echoing $stub lists the following MERGED_VIDEOS_MOV MERGED_VIDEOS_MP4 batch_process_join_wav_mov.sh batch_process_join_wav_mp4.sh m4a movs